# Valor mostrado em produção diferente do desenvolvimento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, oracle

Tenho uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC com o Entity Framework com um banco de dados Oracle, e a mesma esta mostrando alguns dados errados, e isto acontece apenas em produção, no Debug(localmente) os dados são trazidos de forma certa.

Estes dados são gravados a partir de outro sistema. O meu sistema apenas pega os dados, diretamente no banco, sem API, e mostra os dados.

Esta é a função utilizada.

```
public List<Escala> GetByFunc(int motCodigo, DateTime data)
{
    try
    { 
        return Db.Escala.Where(x => x.MotoristaCodigo == motCodigo && x.Data == data)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Data).ToList();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Normativas: sempre coloque o código do que uma imagem, por favor! troque essa imagem de código e coloque o próprio código .

Comment: O que deveria mostrar? e o que está mostrando, poderia melhorar sua pergunta?

Comment: Tu não tá trabalhando com duas bases, por acaso? Uma homologação e outra produção? Olhando dados de uma e pegando de outra?

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas. Esta Função retorna uma Escala de motoristas, e dentro desta escala, há um horário inicial e um final, para o motorista e data especifica, o valor que está vindo errado é do horário. Debugando o código ele traz certo, mas em produção, traz um valor diferente.

Comment: Não Aline, é uma base apenas, não temos base de teste para este sistema.

Comment: Que valor diferente que traz para horário? Não poderia ser as configurações regionais do servidor?

Comment: Não Alina, o valor do horário já é gravado no banco de dados certo. No caso o valor certo é 16:12 mas esta trazendo 05:20, isto dentro do objeto Escala.

Comment: é string no banco?

Comment: Motorista = Number(16), Data = Date, Hora_Inicial = Number(6), Hora_Final = Number(6)

Comment: Ao meu ver os tipos estão corretos.

Comment: Só me parece que está pegando o registro errado mesmo... Tem algum que eh: 05:20?

Comment: voce ta ordenando apenas pela Data .. sendo que o que voce quer é o ultimo horário, então você deveria ordenar pelo `horario`  tambem ...

Comment: Aline, tem muitos registros de 05:20. Mas não tem nenhum no dia 05/04/2017 que é o dia que está dando o problema. E não acho que esteja pegando o registro erado pois localmente o valor é trazido de forma correta, mas em produção vem um valor erado.

Comment: Andre, não mudou nada usando o código que você passou, continua na mesma, localmente traz o valor correto e em produção traz o valor errado.

Comment: @CassioAlves vc disse que seu campo `hora` é number, como que estao os dados na base? de forma crua... 0520 ? 1612 ?

Comment: O outro sistema do qual eu pego os dados está gravando o dado como 982, dai sistema que eu cuido(Já paguei ele pronto) o antigo programador faz umas contas para chegar no valor, que na maioria dos casos é só dividir este valor por 60 que da 16 com inteiro, e pega o resto e faz outras contas. Ma isto está funcionando bem a muito tempo. Tanto é que funciona certo localmente.